# Having A Category Sort Problem. EE3

Tags: categories

I need to sort across all categories based on performance start date. Its all one category group with three categories. It sorts but it will sort one category by date and the second category by date. I want it to span across all three categories and base on star_date display a view of events by date. I am a bit lost can use some help.

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="performances" dynamic="no"   category_group="3" sort="asc" orderby="performance_date_one" }
  <div class="title-event">
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  </div>

  {description_of_event}
  {performance_date_one format="%l, %F %j, %Y"}

   {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using a Bloqs field to orderby. I needed to create a new field out side of Bloqs and it now sorts correctly.